# Limit for pictures on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

What are the limits for pictures on the product page? Is it the total size of the pictures that's limited, the number of pictures or both?

I've gotten fatal errors when I uploaded 9 images and also when the image was 6mb.

This is magento1.9

Update. I uploaded 24 images about 100kb each and at first try the page didn't load right (only pictured loaded, no text, no buttons, everything was blank) On second try it did.

When I try from my phone I get same thing but with errors, but after reloading a few times it loads.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here are the links. Try all 3 products. They're identical.

http://booomchik.com/leashes.html

Can someone please explain what those errors mean? Total size of my pics is 3mb or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're getting is that the server is running out of memory  and cannot process the page anymore. It looks like its running out at about 67mb. Check with your hosting provider and see what memory limit you have and make sure that you have the minimum memory limit `256mb` see magento system requirements (http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements).

Comment: And that's where I'm confused. My pics are 3mb. What's taking up the rest? And I will check with them. So the limit is 256mb per page? Is there any way for me to know how many MB I can use for pictures and how much is taken up by whatever else?

Comment: Its not necessarily the images it could be other process running as well before it even starts to render the page such as loading the product or loading upsell products these all require memory. There may be code in your site that is taking up a lot of memory and it not necessarily the pictures. Magento needs 256mb to run but recommends 512mb. You could use something like newrelic (http://newrelic.com/) to see where the memory is being lost and find bottle necks in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information.

After trying to increase the memory on Godaddy's hosting, it looks like it can't be done. On my version of magento there's no php.ini file, it's called php.inisample, so it's not being used, it's there for reference. The minute I rename it to php.ini the site throws an error and can't be used. Once I rename it to anything other than php.ini the site goes back up.

Godaddy support couldn't help with this, pages with a few images wouldn't load at first try, they would load half blank or with errors or just a blank page. After reloading the page it would load fine.

I had to change hosting.

I'm really curious whether anyone was able to add php.ini to their magento site without errors.